# Lightweight Eclipseplugin for RTC

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

IBM has this big 200+ Mb Eclipse plugin where I'm given access to everything and all functionality of Eclipse.

Is there a smaller more lightweight Eclipse plugin available that just gives access to the information a developer needs. Basically just a list of the workitems assigned to me or my team.

Yes, I can configure the big existing IBM plugin to just display that info, but then I'd still have this massive behemoth installed in my Eclipse.

I am aware of Tasktop Dev that allows me to import the workitems into my mylyn tasklist, but I'm looking for something cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because that plugin would have to manage work items *and* change sets (the list of versioned files), that is the planning *and* the source control part.
Plus you would need the EMF - GMF dependencies, part of the 200+ MB bundle, as described in "[Tip: Installing the Rational Team Concert client into Eclipse 3.5.x](https://jazz.net/library/article/384)".

Which is basically 75% of what the RTC plugin is (the rest being a link to the JBE: Jazz Build Engine).